# How can I get all the files

Tags: tfs

I have a solution.  I select get the latest, it does not....

I have a folder that has 3rd party dlls.  These are not gotten.  Instead I have to go into my source control browser and get the latest.  Programmers forget to do this and their code breaks.

How can I get the latest directly from the solution?

Comment: Are the files part of your solution? I.e. do they appear in solution explorer (without having view all files selected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source control interface in the solution explorer is very poor. I'd recommend using the source control view instead.

The reason that tfs doesn't get all the files when you get latest on the solution explorer is that it only considers files in the solution. If you use the source control view instead, you will get all the files with no messing about.

The other option is to add all the files to your solution. Right click in the solution explorer and add existing file. In the file browser, choose the file and then click the arrow at the right end of the open button to drop down a menu - choose add as link so that the solution references the file where it is rather than taking a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Get Specific Version" and specify "Latest". Also specify to overwrite files that  haven't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add the DLLs directly to the solution in their own solution folder.  Then Visual Studio would know about them and pick them up with the rest of the solution.